# Transfering tokens from runtime pallet to ink smart contract

Tags: ink

I am using the balance pallet in the runtime. I want to install ink contract-pallet so that others can develop smart contracts using runtime pallet functions. I also want to send funds to ink smart contract from the runtime pallet, so that funds can be handled by the ink contract. I am new to ink, can I have such features? How can I do that? Some code snippets will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[Chain Extensions](https://ink.substrate.io/macros-attributes/chain-extension/) are the main way to have contracts interact with the runtime (not the other way around).

However, for an interaction with the native token, [`ink_env::transfer`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_env/fn.transfer.html) might be sufficient.

Also, check `give_me` function in the [contract-transfer](https://github.com/paritytech/ink-examples/blob/main/contract-transfer/lib.rs) example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how to call give_me in runtime pallet?